# Wild Card search for specific fields

Tags: search

I need to develop a search box that allows custom/wild card searches on fields in a Sharepoint site.  The site to be searched is a subsite.  Can anyone suggest the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

In both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 you can use Keyword Query Language to perform this search, though the wildcard only works as a suffix. For Example:

- Author:Matt* will find all items where the Author starts with Matt

You can limit the scope of the search in a couple ways. FOr example you can create a Scope in 2010 or Result Source in 2013 that limits the results to those from the Site. Or you can add the Query Modifier `Site:http://site/subsite` (or similar query, this is off the top of my head).